# How do I use subprocess.Popen to open/run .py files?

Tags: python, subprocess

I read the documentation for subprocess.Popen but I am still a bit confused. I think it might be due to my lack of knowledge in commandline input.

For my purposes, I want to run a python program called `hithere.py` with other command line inputs after it.

ex:

```
/path/to/file/hithere.py command1 command2 command3
```

I am also trying to understand the example arguments in the documentation

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

```
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Could someone explain this logic behind the arguments?

Comment: Which part of the example do you not understand?

Comment: The solutino you want will be something like `subprocess.Popen('python', '/path/to/file/hithere.py', 'command1', 'command2', 'command3')` That's assuming the `python` executable is in the PATH of the script calling `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @TomDalton so if I had the list ['/path/to/file/hithere.py','rm hithere.py','mkdir apple'] I would be able to remove the python file and create a new directory?

Comment: @TomDalton My confusion stems from the list elements being terminal commands. I am not a pro with the terminal so I'm not sure if those are actual terminal commands

Comment: @Liondancer The arguments in the example are just made-up arguments that the example executable  `/bin/vikings` takes. They are not separate commands. The example is really just doing this `/bin/vikings -input "eggs.txt" -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"`

Comment: @Liondancer Are you trying to write some thing that will do three separate actions: 1) execute `hithere.py` 2) remove `hithere.py` 3) create the directory `apple`? Because that's not what will happen if you pass the list `['/path/to/file/hithere.py','rm hithere.py','mkdir apple']` to `subprocess.Popen`. Instead, it will execute `/path/to/file/hithere.py`, with the arguments `'rm hithere.py' and `mkdir apple`.

Comment: @dano I see I understand now. Thank you for clearing this up for me. I thought for subprocess the elements in the list were terminal commands and not arguments to the executable. Thank you for clearing this up